# Error installing SQL Server 2008 - all componets installed successfully except database engine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, installation

Below is the error I copied, please someone help me, I have tried at least 10 times in the last 3 days. It is SQL Server 2008 R2 and I wanted to install it on Windows 7.

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Setup
>
> The following error has occurred:
>
> Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=10.0.1600.22&EvtType=0xE53883A0%25400xBE03358B%25401306%254024

Comment: What does the SQL Server error log contain?

Comment: Sorry I dont know How to check that

Comment: I don't know either, but typing "sql server error log" in google seems to have a few hints :-)

Comment: Go to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log and see the summary.txt as well as Detail.txt files. Also, have a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqljourney/archive/2012/03/16/sql-2008-r2-setup-fails-with-quot-wait-on-the-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed-quot.aspx

Comment: I dont understand things inside the summary.txt file some pasrt of that file is below please help me with easiest way to install MS sqlserver2008 on window7:

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Failed: see details below
  Configuration error code:      0xBE03358B@1306@24
  Configuration error description: Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.

Comment: error log says  "Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes"
I wanted to install sql server 2008 on my window 7 ultimate 32-bit, Can u help me with screen snapshots to install database engine of sqlserver 2008

Comment: Please check the sql server error log as well and tell us what it says C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\MSSQL\LOG

Comment: I got something like below in the gvn directory:
Database Mirroring Transport is disabled in the endpoint configuration.
2013-05-24 17:25:27.69 spid7s      Warning ******************
2013-05-24 17:25:27.69 spid7s      SQL Server started in single-user mode. This an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-05-24 17:25:27.69 spid7s      Starting up database 'master'

Comment: @ShaikhNadeem somewhere in one of the error logs or setup logs there is a reason the install is failing. We have told you where to look. Until that reason is found we can't troubleshoot any further.

Comment: there are no such directory available.
directory available are:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\LOG\exception.log
contents are:
05/07/13 15:29:01 spid 0 Exception 0x400042ac PRINTSTACK at 0x75B89673

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the account doing the installation is a member of the following groups in local security policy:

1. Adjust Memory quotas for a process
2. Bypass Traverse checking
3. Log on as a batch job
4. Log on as a service
5. Replace a process level token
6. Backup files and directories
7. Debug programs
8. Manage auditing and security log

Additional Items to check:
Make sure the account doing the install is a local admin on the server, make sure you are not installing to a compressed drive or folder, make sure you are installing the right version, IE 32 or 64 bit based on your OS

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar problem while Installing SQl server 2012 and after long searching the internet I found the solution.Uninstall the previous installations of SQL Server(including registry files and remaining files) and install again.While installing you need to change the account name for database services to NT AUTHORITYNETWORK SERVICE and it will successfully installed without any errors.
For detailed information with screenshot read this - http://www.superpctricks.com/2014/02/sql-install-error-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed.html